# Out of bounds search item in Python binary search implementations

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

I have implemented the binary search in Python in different ways and I was testing that against a sorted list. The iterative solution is failing when the search item is out of the bounds of the minimum and maximum values of the list.

I have done some initial testing and debugging. I am unable to understand the problem in the implementation.

```py
def bisect_search_itr(L, e):
  low = 0
  high = len(L)
  mid_index = (low + high) // 2
  while low <= high:
    if L[mid_index] == e:
      return True
    else:
      if e > L[mid_index]:
        low = mid_index
      else:
        high = mid_index
    mid_index = (low + high) // 2
  return False

def bisect_search_rec(L, e):
  if L == []:
    return False
  elif len(L) == 1:
    return L[0] == e
  else:
    half = len(L) // 2
    if L[half] > e:
      return bisect_search_rec(L[:half], e)
    else:
      return bisect_search_rec(L[half:], e)

def bisect_search_rec_with_bounds(e, m, n):
  if m == n:
    return L[m] == e
  else:
    half = m+n//2
    if L[half] == e:
      return True
    else:
      if e < L[half]:
        return bisect_search_rec_with_bounds(e, m, half)
      else: 
        return bisect_search_rec_with_bounds(e, half, n)

# Test case
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
x = 17

print(bisect_search_itr(L, x))
print(bisect_search_rec(L, x))
print(bisect_search_rec_with_bounds(x, 0, len(L) - 1))
```

The recursive implementations are doing fine but for the iterative implementation, it runs into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the line `while low <= high:` and the only exit from that loop being through `L[mid_index] == e`. In your example data, the target element is not within the list. After a few iterations, all of low, high and mid_index will be at the highest number of the list.

Depending on how you want to implement this, you can either return the closest number (15), or throw an error if `low` and `high` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to debug this problem. Just attach a debugger (or use print statements) to see that the root cause for your infinite loop is that after a certain point (when `low` and `high` get close to each other`) nothing in your loop changes.

Let's see a very simplified example: `L = [1, 2]`, `x = 5`. In this case, `low = 1`, `high = 2`, `mid_index = 1`. Inside the loop you'll see that the element is greater than mid, so you'll set `low = mid_index` to 1 and finally `mid_index` to 1. So nothing has changed. You didn't really increment nor `low`, neither `mid_index`, thus the infinite loop. For any `L` not containing `x`, after enough iterations, you'll find this exact scenario inside the loop.

To fix the problem, make sure that for each iteration either `low` or `high` changes. For example, since you already check that the `mid_index` element is not what you're looking for, it's safe to set `low` to `mid_index + 1`.